# Is it necessary to use return withContext(Dispatchers.IO)?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm using Firebase authentication. In the repository I have this function:

```
override suspend fun signIn(): Result<Boolean> {
    return try {
        auth.signInAnonymously().await()
        Result.Success(true)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        Result.Failure(ex)
    }
}
```

This function is called from within the ViewModel class:

```
var response by mutableStateOf<Result<Boolean>>(Result.Success(false))
    private set

fun signIn() = viewModelScope.launch {
    response = repository.signIn()
}
```

Which works fine but I was suggested to use in the ViewModel:

```
fun signIn() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    response = repository.signIn()
}
```

To add `Dispatchers.IO` and inside the repository:

```
override suspend fun signIn(): Result<Boolean> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            auth.signInAnonymously().await()
            Result.Success(true)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Result.Failure(ex)
        }
    }
}
```

To launch a coroutine using `withContext`. I and I don't understand why? I'm using Jetpack Compose.

Comment: This code waits on firebase by suspending (`await()`), so you don't have to / shouldn't use `Dispatchers.IO` here. `Dispatchers.IO` is only required for blocking IO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoever suggested changing your code is wrong.

It is a general Kotlin coroutines convention that suspend functions never need to be called on a specific dispatcher, specifically because they must never block. They always internally delegate to a specific dispatcher if they need one. (But perhaps as an optimization, a *private* suspend function might avoid doing it for a function that must be called on the Main dispatcher.)

Since this is a convention, all the libraries from Google, Android, Square, etc. and anyone else who knows what they're doing, only have `suspend` functions that can be called from *any* dispatcher.

This includes the `await()` call you're using with Firebase. Therefore, your repository's `signIn` function is already perfectly fine as-is. Since it doesn't call any blocking functions, and the suspend function it calls is a proper suspend function that also does not block, it conforms to the standard (it doesn't block).

The function in your ViewModel is also fine. No dispatcher needs to be specified.

Answer (score 0):

We have a two ways to start coroutine async and launch.

1. **launch** will use to perform serial/sequence task in background.
2. **async** is used when we expect some result back and also want to perform parallel operation.

Same way **withContext** is nothing but another way of writing the async where one does not have to write await(). When withContext, is used, it runs the tasks in series instead of parallel. So one should remember that when we have a single task in the background and want to get back the result of that task, we should use withContext.

In your case you can change your code as below

```
fun signIn() = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val response = async {  repository.signIn()}.await()
    }
```

and remove **withContext**

```
 suspend fun signIn(): Result<Boolean> {
     return try {
         auth.signInAnonymously().await()
         Result.Success(true)
     } catch (ex: Exception) {
         Result.Failure(ex)
     }
}
```

One more way if you don't want to use return with **withContext**

```
override suspend fun signIn() = {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            auth.signInAnonymously().await()
            Result.Success(true)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Result.Failure(ex)
        }
    }
}
```

In Nutshell if you expecting some result from your task then you have to use **async** or **withContext**.

Hope I am able to solve your problem or issue.

Comment: There's no point in ever using the `async { ... }.await()` pattern. The compiler even gives you a warning if you do it. It should be `withContext` instead. But you only need that if you are calling a **blocking** function, which isn't happening here.